# How to correctly tie in electrical lines to Tankless WH

Tags: electrical, conduit

I installed this electric tankless water heater a few years ago. It is the Eco Smart 18. We are now trying to sell our house and the inspection has advised that the electrical lines be run in conduit. All of the installation videos have the wires running without conduit.

What sort of conduit fixtures would you use to conceal these wires?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated based on confirmation that the hole in the wall is *not* a junction box.

This is not a *big* problem because you have cables going through the wall, not individual wires. If you had individual wires loose in the wall they would have to be pulled out and replaced with cable or install conduit and run through conduit, but fortunately that is not the case.

You have 2 cables, one for each 240V 40A circuit. However, they are /3 cables - black/red/white - instead of /2 cables - black and white. As a result, you have an extra white wire in each cable, which would normally be used for neutral. The water heater doesn't need neutral, and the "solution" was to rip out the white and stick it in the wall. You can't do that.

The proper solution would be to run the cables, intact, all the way into the bottom of the water heater and cap the neutral there. If you have enough slack in the cable to do that then chop off the butchered ends of the cables and run intact cables through the clamp into the water heater, terminate black and red properly, cap the white and attach the bare ground properly.

But most of the time people don't have any slack in the cable. There is also a possibility here that the full /3 cables won't fit through the clamp, or that the space inside the water heater is too small to include the capped white wire. In any of those problems apply:

- Install a proper metal junction box in the wall. Preferably a big metal box, because I don't like plastic. It needs to be fairly big because it needs to be large enough for 2 incoming /3 cables and 2 outgoing /2 cables or sets of wire. Based on [this calculator](https://www.constructionmonkey.com/calculations/misc/boxfill) just the 2 terminated wires (white) and the 8 spliced wires (black/red in and out x 2) requires 30 cubic inches, and the grounds will add some more. A 42 cubic inch box would work well.

There are two options coming out of the box - wire and cable. Cable is probably going to be the easiest solution because otherwise you will need to figure out how to connect conduit to the water heater.

- Get about 3 feet of 8 AWG /2 NM cable. Cut it in half.
- Strip 6" of outer sheath of each end of each cable.
- Attach the black and red wires to each cable to a matching pair of wires from an existing /3 cable with appropriate wire nuts.
- All ground wires go together and to a ground screw on the metal box.
- Attach the other end of the two /2 cables to the water heater, connecting black and red to the hot terminals and ground to the water heater - there should be a clearly marked place for the ground wires.
- You will need a clamp on the junction box cover. If you get the right size, you should be able to use one clamp for both cables. If you can find a cover with the right size knockout for the matching clamp then this is really easy.
- The cable sheath should end just inside each clamp (water heater and junction box). Outside you should just see nice clean cable sheath.

Comment: Grounding is required. It's explained in the instructions but not shown on the wiring diagram. There are pictures online that show a ground bus bar next to the hot wire bus bars.

Comment: Well, it's in the electrical code, it doesn't need to be in the instructions.  While most videos are *just awful*, I would be surprised if any videos said to split a jacket outside the enclosure like that, also not in the instructions.  Even the Hillbilly Electrical Code doesn't allow this. This is rather lazy work, and the chickens coming home to roost. As we warn people will happen.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateUkraine My hunch is that the problem started with using /3 instead of /2 therefore "what do we do with the white wire". And the rest is history.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact  Yes, and both cables intact wouldn't fit into the connector.

Comment: @JACK That's a bit surprising. It should be designed to accept two standard cables and have an internal junction box (or equivalent) to connect everything.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact  So far, I'm not impressed with the unit or the installation manuals. Glad I'm not a fan of tankless.

Comment: It is not a junction box, it is just a hole in the wall.